Measure to what extent the trades/profit are evenly distributed over time
current situation:
I have several trading strategies which are working well. Unfortunately the trades are not evenly distributed over time. In some months I have several trades (so profit increases in short time), then a month with no trades etc...
Goal: I want to run several trading strategies in parallel to have a more or less stable increase in profit (which is more or less related to the number of trades - no every trade is a win)
In order to see which strategies are fitting well together I need some number/metrics. But I'm not sure what to measure/calculate.
This is an example showing the number of trades per month (sorry the image is not shown in the post directly):
https://imgur.com/a/thvV5K7

The first image at imgur above shows the starting situation.
On the second image you can see, that the distribution is spread more evenly, e.g. on 2023-03 and 2024-02 the number of trades increased.

Question: How can I measure how evenly the number of trades per month are distributed? I tried standard deviation but that doesn't work.
E.g. having many months with zero trades: Adding a trade to such a month would increase the standard deviation which is "wrong" as would like to have additional trades on such months.
Question: I'm not 100% satisfied to use the number of trades per month as the key figure. I would like to rely more on the profit or include the profit in the measurement how well several strategies fit together. And ideas?

Update:
Some background information in case somebody has other approaches:
Let's say I have found (via backtesting) 500 different strategies which make good profit with a small max. drawdown and high hit ratio (I'm focusing on these metrics right now). Unfortunately many of these strategies behave similarly (making the trades at the same time but with different profit/stop loss).
Now I want to choose the best e.g. 10 strategies out of these 500 which fit well together. "Fitting well together" means in my opinion: they are not too similar --> the graph of my profit has less outliers (up and down) and is smoother. When trading with real money, I prefer stable income instead of high ups and downs although when still making profit at the end of the day (my nerves are thankful for this approach).
Besides instead of just running on strategy with 100\$ I'm running 10 strategies with each 10$. By separating the money in 10 different strategies I want to get more diversity in which stocks/coins/... I'm holding my money.
Thank's very much!

I do not yet understand why there exists an ultimate requirement of evenly spaced trades.
Regarding your question, you could have a look at this question + answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122668/is-there-a-measure-of-evenness-of-spread

@Kermittfrog I added some more background information to my post. Thank's for this link. This fits to my goal but it feels too complicated. My gut feeling says there must be an easier approach to measure such metrics.
